# How can I stop Microsoft Word from switching to another space when last window in current space is closed

Tags: macos, ms-office, spaces

If I close the last window of Microsoft Word on Desktop 1, and there is an open Microsoft Word window on Desktop 2, I am automatically swooshed over to Desktop 2. This behavior does not occur for other apps like Safari or Finder. How can I disable this automatic space swooshing for Microsoft Word?

Comment: Try going to system preferences, mission control and uncheck "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application"

Comment: Tried that. The behavior persists. Any other ideas?

Comment: if I had my Mac with me right now >.> most I can say is look in all of Word's settings by clicking the bolded "word" on the top menu bar and seeing if there are any preferences.

Comment: Good suggestion. But, not seeing anything relevant there.

Comment: Well I'm going to resort to eccentric ideas. Duplicate the word app and open the files in separate apps. So you could have a word app for space 1, one for space 2 and etc. try this if no one else can figure out an official solution.

Comment: Definitely an outside the box idea and appreciated, but that would probably require more cognitive effort and consternation than the original issue for me. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool NO

killall Dock
```

Credit to jgl777 for [their post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4995042). Wanted to repost here so that it is easier for people to find.